# Choose VC++ runtime version of an MFC project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, runtime

I created a MFC project with VS2013 and it works fine on my computer. But it won't run on a computer without VC++ Redistribution 2013 installed.
Can I specify a lower VC++ runtime version of an MFC project in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think even if it is lower vc++ runtime version, you may face similar problem.
If you can tolerate exe file is larger than before, just change the value of **Use of MFC** to **Use MFC in a Static Library** in project property page. By doing so, you don't need to distribute mfc modules related.
Otherwise, you have to distribute relative mfc modules such as mfc100.dll.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235265.aspx) may help you.

Comment: Thanks! The depends.exe is an amazing tool!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create installation package for your program. As Visual Studio user, you can create an installation with InstallShield Limited Edition. Installation package should contain correct  C++ and MFC runtime version for your program.

See also:

InstallShield Limited Edition http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531020.aspx\

Walkthrough: Deploying Your Program (C++) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384837.aspx

Specifically, to add VC++ Runtime: On the Redistributables tab in the editor window, select the Visual C++ 11.0 CRT check box. If you use MFC, check also MFC redistribution.

Comment: Thanks! But I prefer the integration way. Thank you all the same.